# Heroku issue with Rails 4 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

I am working on getting a site up on the web through heroku. I have done this four times before but on the fifth I ran into some issues. To start, I did successfully get the app up but it was a test app. I decided to delete it and get the same code up but under a different name. (I know maybe should have asked here how to change the name.) Anyways, after I deleted the app on Heroku and tried to push the app again I got this message, which came right after git push heroku master:

```
remote: !   No such app as food-test.
fatal: repository 'https://git.heroku.com/food-test.git/' not found
```

On Heroku the apps name, that I deleted, was food-test. In Github and on my desktop the rails project is called food_blog. The new name that I wanted to call the site, on heroku, was chefwife. Anyways, I looked here on heroku to try and solve this problem and got what I thought was a response. So, I did what the answer said which was to type the following two lines:

```
git remote remove heroku 
git remote add heroku https://github.com/ravenusmc/Food_blog.git
```

I thought everything was fine but when I type git push heroku master it asks me for my github username and password and pushed there. This is where my problem is. How do I get it to push to Heroku again? If I go a git remote -v I see the following:

```
heroku  https://github.com/ravenusmc/Food_blog.git (fetch)
heroku  https://github.com/ravenusmc/Food_blog.git (push)
origin  https://github.com/ravenusmc/Food_blog.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/ravenusmc/Food_blog.git (push)
```

Any help in solving this problem will be a great help! Have a great day!

Comment: Try `git remote remove heroku` followed by `heroku create`

Comment: Once you are able to create remote for heroku, you should be able to rename the app easily with `heroku apps:rename chefwife`, although it depends on its availability.

Comment: He does not need/want to run `heroku create` if he already has an existing heroku app.

Comment: He deleted the app on Heroku.

Comment: Vishal your first comment worked! Thank you and the site is now up! Have a great day!

Comment: Glad to hear that. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

okay let's understand what's happening here. 
when you create an app with Heroku with `heroku create APP_NAME` 
It creates a new app on Heroku and add a new remote to github repository with the name `heroku` and set the reference for this remote meaning when you will push to heroku with `git push heroku master` it knows where to push code it will be something like `https://git.heroku.com/APP_NAME.git`

So it will push the code to this link.

When you deleted the app from heroku this link became invalid so that error occurred.

After that you ran `git remote add heroku https://github.com/ravenusmc/Food_blog.git` which is saying add a new remote reference to github which is still pointing to your actual github repository. So when you will push the code this will be pushed to your github repository which is `https://github.com/ravenusmc/Food_blog.git`

So all you had to do was create a new app for heroku it will add the new reference named heroku and will work fine. So here are steps to fix it.

`git remote remove heroku`

`heroku create chefwife` #This will create a new app and add the reference to your new app.

after that everything is cool you can check the remotes again by `git remote -v` as you will see it will be like

`heroku https://git.heroku.com/chefwife.git`

If you have already created your app then you can just add a new `remote` reference by

`git remote add heroku https://git.heroku.com/chefwife.git`

Comment: Yes! This all worked and thank you for the detailed explanation to help me understand Heroku and github better!

Answer (score 0):

It is best if you connect your github repo to heroku and allow automatic deployment. This will make your life easier.

Please refer https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/github-integration to get it done.